# Automatically resize textbox to fit available space

Tags: css

Can I have a fixed size row div where the input resizes automatically to take the available space, but everything in the row div is in the same line? (The first row below would have the same width as the second row, because the input in the second row would shrink automatically).

```
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" />
</div>

<div class="row">
    <span class="leftText">Text</span>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CqCax/

Comment: Are you allow to change your HTML?

Comment: @Vucko Yes, I can change the HTML if it will make it easier.

Comment: This is an interesting question :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

-- HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" />
</div>

<div class="row">
    <span class="leftText">Text</span>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

-- CSS

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
    display:table;
    width: 200px; 
}
span {
    width: 1%;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
input, span {
    display:table-cell;
} 
input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9aAse/4/

Its a little hacky way tho.

Comment: Thanks, just what I wanted.

Comment: Nice. Thanks! Weird how it requires the width to be set to something.

Comment: yeah, tables are weird :|

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can.

```
display: -webkit-flex;
```

Full code:
http://jsfiddle.net/frapporti/gXLeK/

Comment: Interesting. It's simple but since it splits up the left text into two lines if it gets too big, I can't use it.

Comment: This works on Chrome. I've tried adding the -ms css properties too, but it doesn't seem to work on IE.

Comment: should work in IE10, for older browsers you can add the older box method along with a polyfill.. too bad i can't test at the moment